# How to Update OpenSSL on Mac OS 10.15.7

Tags: macos, ssl

We are running on Mac OS 10.15.7 and we have been told by some APIs that our TLS is not up to date.

When I run: openssl version
I get: LibreSSL 2.8.3

When I run: which openssl
I get: /usr/bin/openssl

How do I update this to something that has at least TLS 1.2?

Comment: macOS has been TLS 1.2 compatible since 10.9. You must be using some old 3rd party structure to have LibreSSL, which is currently at v3.4.2 - https://www.libressl.org

Comment: @Tetsujin: This old LibreSSL version is actually shipped by default with MacOS, before that it was the even older OpenSSL version 0.9.8. Looks like Apple does not really care about the OpenSSL or OpenSSL compatible TLS stack.

Comment: *"How do I update this to something that has at least TLS 1.2?"* - LibreSSL 2.8.3 has support for TLS 1.2. So if this is your actual requirement then this is matched. If you have different requirements then please update your question to show these. Just stating *"have been told by some APIs that our TLS is not up to date"* is not a requirement one can work with. Also note that your unknown application might not even use the OpenSSL/LibreSSL but might use a different TLS stack or might come with its own (older) version.